Avro maven plugin can't redefine type
I am using the avro-maven-plugin inside a quarkus project:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.3</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.avsc</include>
                </includes>
                <imports>
                    <import>A.avsc</import>
                    <import>B.avsc</import>
                </imports>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

The question is about the imports section in the plugin.
The documentation says that the imported files should not reference eachother, however in my case both file A and B need to be imported and B references A.
As far as I understand, this is not possible and fails with:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.6.6:dev (default-cli) on project : Unable to execute mojo: Execution null of goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema failed: Can't redefine:  -> [Help 1]
Is there any workaround?

Check if you are using the quarkus-maven-plugin with the generate-code goal. In such a case, building with maven compile will work (as you have described), since only the plugin and the configuration you defined will be used. Using quarkus:dev with the above-mentioned generate-code goal will also start compiling Avro files, but without your import configurations, since another plugin is used.
Since you are using Quarkus, I suggest utilizing their way of Avro schema generation. In this case, you will need to list imports in your Quarkus config file under avro.codegen.avsc.imports. More info in
Quarkus documentation about tweaking avro code gen ;)
